# How to get rid of stuck splash screen?

Tags: linux, eclipse

My eclipse hung on startup at the splash screen.  I eventually gave up and killed the process, but the splash screen is still there.  Is there a way to locate it's root process and kill it, or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will show you all processes with the word eclipse in the name, so if the splash screen process has eclipse in the name it will show up.

```
 ps aux | grep eclipse
```

If "eclipse" is not in the name of the process of the splash screen it will be a bit harder to find, you could try just running `ps aux`  by itself and then looking closely through the resulting list.

If you still can't find it then you could just log out of the desktop. All visual processes will be stopped when you log out.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Some crazy java process.  Thanks.